# How to use ``saveAs`` to direct pdf download on the server

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, kendo-ui

Currently, I'm using Kendo UI to export PDFs. I export and download the PDF using this method:
`kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs` and it downloads it on my PC. What I'm trying to do though, is to direct the pdf somehow to a php script for it to be possible to download the PDF on my server's file system, because I know JS can't access the server.

This is the component I'm using currently: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/pdf-export

Comment: You can upload the downloaded pdf file to your server using Ajax, After the saveAs promise complete.

Comment: So, the saveAs promise downloads the file to my PC. So, you're suggesting that I get the path of the downloaded file and then upload that file on the server? Not a bad idea but, looking for better suggestions.

Comment: No better solution buddy, Since the creation of pdf file, is happening on the client-side.

Comment: Example how to do it by converting it into a blob first right there: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/pdf-output/overview#using-the-blob-object